# How to justifyContent in headerContent horizontally?

Tags: sapui5

I am using a ObjectPageLayout with headerContent and I want to justifyContent so it will have space between items in the headerContent but it won't work.
This works only out of the headerContent, how can I do something similar in headerContent?

```
<FlexBox
                alignItems="Start"
                justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                <items>
                    <Button text="1" type="Accept" />
                    <Button text="2" type="Reject" />
                </items>
            </FlexBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the predefined css classes like

```
"sapUiTinyMarginBeginEnd, sapUiLargeMarginTopBottom,..."
```

for styling purposes. I use `alignItems` and `justifyContent` only for rough item structuring.

Comment: how can i use them to have a result of 3 separeted sections? right, center and left.

Answer (score 0):

anp156 is right. have a look at this site: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/777168ffe8324873973151dae2356d1c

this is an overview of predefined css classes for margin etc.